# filter html post before save/publish wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i want filter html post code before publish or save or update to clean it from html att tags like id , class , style for html h1 , h2 , h3 , h4 , h5 , h6 , span , p , b , strong ,ol , etc so after save post output in editor from database well back clean without any style or id or class

so example old code before do filter

```
<h3 id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9." style="color:blue"><span id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9.">text example</span></h3>
text example
<h4><span id=".A7.D9.84.D8.BA.D8.AF.D8.A9_." style="color:red" class=".A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D9.">text example</span></h4>
text example
<h2><span id="D9.82.D9.8A." class="AF.D8.">text example</span></h4>
text example
<h3><span id="AF.D8.B1.D9.82.D9.8A.D8.A9" class="82.D9.8A.D8.A9">text example</span></h3>
<ul id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9."><li id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9." style="color:black">test</li></ul>
```

want it to be in post after publish or save or update any post in database like this after filter

```
<h3><span>text example</span></h3>
text example
<h4><span>text example</span></h4>
text example
<h2><span>text example</span></h4>
text example
<h3><span>text example</span></h3>
<ul><li>test</li></ul>
```

hope help me

Comment: try to use php *preg_replace()* function or use javascript to clean and submit through ajax

Comment: please add more expalin to that

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work out

```
<?php
$data = '<h3 id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9." style="color:blue"><span id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9.">text example</span></h3>
text example
<h4><span id=".A7.D9.84.D8.BA.D8.AF.D8.A9_." style="color:red" class=".A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D9.">text example</span></h4>
text example
<h2><span id="D9.82.D9.8A." class="AF.D8.">text example</span></h4>
text example
<h3><span id="AF.D8.B1.D9.82.D9.8A.D8.A9" class="82.D9.8A.D8.A9">text example</span></h3>
<ul id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9."><li id=".D8.AF.D8.A9_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8" class="A7.D9." style="color:black">test</li></ul>';

$html = preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $data);
$html = preg_replace('/id=".*?"/', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('/style=".*?"/', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $html);
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: how this work with wordpress!!

Comment: sorry bro i dont know about wordpress. Have your problem solved?

Comment: hope sameone help i dont know how do it with wordpress that i need